# Any named directions for a 4th spacial dimension?

Tags: soft-question, visualization

Given our 3-dimensional perspective of the universe, we have created the relative spacial directions of left, right, up, down, forward, and backward, which more or less correspond to the mathematical measurements of length, height, and width. Now, there is a measurement (of which I'm vaguely aware of) coined by Henry More called *spissitude*, for the hypothetical travels along a 4th spacial dimension. To phrase my question as an analogy, height is to up and down as *spissitude* is to what?

Thanks!

Comment: More's terminology is not widely used, and moreover seemed to be restricted to a weird philosophical theory. Whether anyone has ever coined the appropriate terms to analogize "up and down" with respect to "essential spissitude" is an open question, but my feeling is probably not.

Comment: I guess you are aware of Hinton's terms "ana" and "kata." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Howard_Hinton

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip I.e., “up” and “down.”

Answer (score 4):

The ones I use are 'ana' and 'kata', which are on the 4-Dimensional space page on Wikipedia[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space) 'ana' and 'kata' as down and up, respectively

Answer (score 0):

I think the most intuitive answer is that spissitude is to *forward* and *backward* as height is to *up* and *down*. You could imagine a particle moving in four dimensions, and easily communicate that it is "moving back and forth in the 4th spacial dimension".

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I mean. Imagine you are at [0,0,0,0] (the 4th value being spissitude), and you move to [0, 0, 0, 1]. Instead of saying "I moved one unit right", you would have to say "I moved one unit forward in the 4th dimension!" It's a rather bulky 8 syllable term, is what I'm saying.